# Generate Random Data from fitted curve - Matlab

Tags: matlab

I fitted a curve that has as equation y = a*x^b+c. I have the curve parameters (a,b,c with the respective bounds), but now according to this model I would generate for each value of x (e.g. from 0 to 100, step 0.1) a set of possible values that y can have.

In details, in Matlab starting from `[fitresult, gof] = fit( xData, yData, ft, opts );` I would generate the aforementioned data structure where each point for each value of x is generated according the interval at 95%.

**Example**
[image]

I took a look to the `randn` and `random` functions.

Any help?

Comment: I'm not getting your question at all

Comment: Ok, you can imagine that from the equation that I have I want to generate a set of points (think about a scatter plot). The generated points should be generated according the equation. I'll put a sketch on the question to explain better what I mean.

Comment: OK but where should be the bounds?

Comment: have a look at `mvnrnd`. You could loop through the individual points and put the ideal points as mean value =)